# Sort a dictionary alphabetically, and print it by frequency

Tags: python, dictionary, tabular, alphabetical

I am running python 2.7.2 on a mac.

I have a simple dictionary:

```
dictionary= {a,b,c,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,a,w,w,p,r}
```

I want it to be printed and have the output like this:

```
Dictionary in alphabetical order:
    a  4
    b  5
    c  2
    p  1
    r  1
    w  2
```

But what I'm getting is something like this...

```
a  1
a  1
a  1
a  1
b  1
.
.
.
w  1
```

This is the code I am using.

```
new_dict = []


    for word in dictionary.keys():
        value = dictionary[word]
        string_val = str(value)
        new_dict.append(word + ": " + string_val)

    sorted_dictionary = sorted(new_dict)

    for entry in sorted_dictionary:
        print entry
```

Can you please tell me where is the mistake?
(By the way, I'm not a programmer but a linguist, so please go easy on me.)

Comment: syntax of `dictionary`  is wrong.Please correct it with the one you are using in your program

Comment: that is a `set`, not a dictionary, and the second that you declare it as a literal it removes all the duplicates.

Comment: That is whatever, less a dictionary!

Comment: [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're using is not a dictionary, it's a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)! :)

And sets doesn't allow duplicates.

What you probably need is not dictionaries, but lists.

**A little explanation**

Dictionaries have keys, and each unique keys have their own values:

```
my_dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

You retrieve values by using the keys:

```
>>> my_dict [1]
'a'
```

On the other hand, a list doesn't have keys.

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']
```

And you retrieve the values using their index:

```
>>> my_list[1]
'b'
```

Keep in mind that indices starts counting from zero, not 1.

**Solving The Problem**

Now, for your problem. First, store the characters as a list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'w', 'w', 'p', 'r']
```

Next, we'll need to know what items are in this list:

```
items = []
for item in l:
    if item not in items:
        items.append(item)
```

This is pretty much equal to `items = set(l)` (the only difference is that this is a list). But just to make things clear, hope you understand what the code does.

Here is the content of `items`:

```
>>> items
['a', 'b', 'c', 'w', 'p', 'r']
```

With that done, we will use [`lst.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method to see the number of a char's occurence in your list, and the built-in function [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the items:

```
for item in sorted(items): #iterates through the sorted items.
    print item, l.count(item)
```

**Result:**

```
a 4
b 5
c 2
w 2
p 1
r 1
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the obvious, this:

```
dictionary= {a,b,c,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,a,w,w,p,r}
```

is not a dictionary.  It is a `set`, and `set`s do not preserve duplicates.  You probably meant to declare that as a `list` or a `tuple`.

Now, onto the meat of your problem: you need to implement something to *count* the items of your collection.  Your implementation doesn't really do that.  You could roll your own, but really you should use a `Counter`:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','a','w','w','p','r']

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(my_list)

c
Out[19]: Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'w': 2, 'p': 1, 'r': 1})
```

Now on to your next problem: dictionaries (of all types, including `Counter` objects) do not preserve key order.  You need to call `sorted` on the dict's `items()`, which is a list of tuples, then iterate over that to do your printing.

```
for k,v in sorted(c.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k,v))

a: 4
b: 5
c: 2
p: 1
r: 1
w: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary is something like this`{key1:content1, key2:content2, ...}` key in a dictionary is unique. then `a = {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,5,6}` is the set, when you print this out, you will notice that

```
print a
set([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

duplicates are eliminated.

In your case, a better data structure you can use is a list which can hold multiple duplicates inside.

if you want to count the element number inside, a better option is [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), for instance:

```
import collections as c
cnt = c.Counter()
dict= ['a','b','c','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','a','w','w','p','r']
for item in dict:
    cnt[item]+=1
print cnt
```

the results would be:

```
Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'w': 2, 'p': 1, 'r': 1})
```

as you notice, the results become a dictionary here.

so by using:

```
for key in cnt.keys():
    print key, cnt[key]
```

you can access the key and content

```
a 4
c 2
b 5
p 1
r 1
w 2
```

you can achieve what you want by modifying this a little bit. hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Dictionary cannot be defined as {'a','b'}. If it defined so, then it is an set, where you can't find duplicates in the list
2. If your defining a character, give it in quotes unless it is declared already.
3. You can't loop through like this `for word in dictionary.keys():`, since here dictionary is not a dictionary type.

If you like to write a code without using any builtin function, try this

```
input=['a','b','c','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','a','w','w','p','r']
dict={}
for x in input:
        if x in dict.keys():
                dict[x]=dict[x]+1
        else:
                dict[x]=1

for k in dict.keys():
    print k, dict[k]
```

Answer (score -1):

First, a dictionary is an unordered collection (i.e., it has no guaranteed order of its keys).

Second, each dict key must be unique.

Though you could count the frequency of characters using a dict, there's a better the solution.  The `Counter` class in Python's `collections` module is based on a dict and is specifically designed for a task like tallying frequency.

```
from collections import Counter

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'w', 'w', 'p', 'r']
cnt = Counter(letters)
print cnt
```

The contents of the counter are now:

`Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'w': 2, 'p': 1, 'r': 1})`

You can print these conveniently:

```
for char, freq in sorted(cnt.items()): 
    print char, freq
```

which gives:

```
a 4
b 5
c 2
p 1
r 1
w 2
```

Comment: Feel free to explain the down vote, and I can help clarify or add more depth to the answer if needed.